# How to NOT include certain no. of patterns in the output?

Tags: bash, shell, grep, pattern-matching

I have a command -

```
some command | egrep -i "($query_value)"
```

which returns lines like -

```
> 2018-01-12 23:17:05.097 Info: Deleted 6 MB at 1129 MB/sec
> /Meters/00002c97 2018-01-12 23:17:05.104 Info: Deleted 6 MB at 864
> MB/sec /Meters/00002c99 2018-01-12 23:26:00.751 Info: Saving
> /Meters/00002c9a 2018-01-12 23:26:01.235 Info: Saved 6 MB at 12 MB/sec
> to /Meters/00002c9a 2018-01-12 23:26:01.268 Info: Merging 12 MB from
> /Meters/00002c9b and /Meters/00002c9a to /Meters/00002c9d,
> timestamp=15158205609400820 2018-01-12 23:26:04.248 Info: Deleted 9 MB
> at 3898 MB/sec /Meters/00002c9b 2018-01-12 23:26:04.250 Info: Deleted
> 6 MB at 2973 MB/sec /Meters/00002c9a 2018-01-12 23:34:01.420 Info:
> Saving /Meters/00002c9c 2018-01-12 23:34:02.192 Info: Saved 6 MB in 1
> sec at 8 MB/sec to /Meters/00002c9c 2018-01-12 23:34:02.248 Info:
> Merging 44 MB from /Meters/00002c98, /Meters/00002c9d, and
> /Meters/00002c9c to /Meters/00002c9f, timestamp=15158210419400730
> 2018-01-12 23:34:07.173 Info: Deleted 35 MB at 9431 MB/sec
> /Meters/00002c98 2018-01-12 23:34:07.175 Info: Deleted 12 MB at 6633
> MB/sec /Meters/00002c9d 2018-01-12 23:34:07.177 Info: Deleted 6 MB at
> 2869 MB/sec /Meters/00002c9c 2018-01-12 23:42:00.842 Info: Saving
> /Meters/00002c9e 2018-01-12 23:42:01.323 Info: Saved 6 MB at 12 MB/sec
> to /Meters/00002c9e 2018-01-12 23:51:00.951 Info: Saving
> /Meters/00002ca0 2018-01-12 23:51:01.680 Info: Saved 6 MB in 1 sec at
> 8 MB/sec to /Meters/00002ca0 2018-01-12 23:51:01.684 Info: Merging 10
> MB from /Meters/00002c9e and /Meters/00002ca0 to /Meters/00002ca2,
> timestamp=15158220605927080 2018-01-12 23:51:05.083 Info: Deleted 6 MB
> at 2127 MB/sec /Meters/00002c9e 2018-01-12 23:51:05.085 Info: Deleted
> 6 MB at 2933 MB/sec /Meters/00002ca0 2018-01-12 23:58:01.110 Info:
> Saving /Meters/00002ca1 2018-01-12 23:58:02.011 Info: Saved 6 MB in 1
> sec at 7 MB/sec to /Meters/00002ca1 2018-01-12 23:58:02.017 Info:
> Merging 12 MB from /Meters/00002ca2 and /Meters/00002ca1 to
> /Meters/00002ca4, timestamp=15158224804450160 2018-01-12 23:58:05.096
> Info: Deleted 9 MB at 419 MB/sec /Meters/00002ca2 2018-01-12
> 23:58:05.105 Info: Deleted 6 MB at 668 MB/sec /Meters/00002ca1
```

but further I want to exclude lines that contains patterns like `merging*mb*from|merged*mb*from`. I don't want lines like -

```
Merging 12 MB from or Merged 12 MB from .
```

I tried using grep's -v option but seems like it doesn't understand **case sensitivity** and 'AND', 'OR' operations.

Answer (score 0):

Try `grep` `-E` (extended regex) `-i` (ignore case) `-v` (invert match):

```
grep -E -i -v 'merg(ing|ed).*mb.*from'
```

If you think "ignore case" is slow, then:

```
grep -E -v '[Mm]erg(ing|ed).*[Mm][Bb].*[Ff]rom'
```

Answer (score 0):

Following `sed` may help you in same.

```
sed -n '/Merging.*MB.*from/d;/Merged.*MB.*from/d;p'   Input_file
```

OR

```
sed -n '/[mM]erging.*[mM][bB].*from/d;/Merged.*MB.*from/d;p'  Input_file
```

***EDIT:*** Adding explanation too here for above code.

```
sed -n '                 ##-n will STOP printing by default for any line of Input_file till we print it explicitly.
/Merging.*MB.*from/d;    ##Looking for string Merging.*MB.*from and using d will skip it and will NOT print it.
/Merged.*MB.*from/d;     ##Looking for string Merged.*MB.*from and using d will skip it and will not print it.
p                        ##mentioning p will print the lines apart from lines which have above mentioned string in them
' Input_file             ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: can you explain what this will do ?

Comment: @rishabhv66, please check my edited explanation with code and kindly do let me know in case of any queries.

Comment: @rishabhv66, check my code after OR now, that takes cares of case sensitive mb|MB etc too.

Comment: ok I'm gonna replace 'some command' with this - sed -n '/2018-01-12 03:0[3-9]/,/2018-01-12 23:59/p' $log_file. This filters the log file and extract lines within the time range given. First of all can you explain me how this works. I used 'p' here too, so technically it should not print  the filtered lines but it id doing the reverse. And if you could combine the 2 seds, it would be great. That way i don't have to use piple '|' symbol.

Comment: @rishabhv66, comments are NOT proper place to ask questions please open new thread for new questions so we all could learn.